# Как лучше хранить данные в MongoDB (комменты)

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Подскажите, как все же правильнее будет хранить комменты к постам - в одной коллекции с постами или же все-таки выносить из в отдельную коллекцию.

Например, имеется коллекция post:

```
{
   "_id": "id",
   "url": "url",
   "data": "какие то данные",
   "created": "время создания",
   "text": "текст поста",
   "comments": [
       {
          "_id": "id commenta",
          "comment": "text",
          "createdBy": "кто создал"
       }
   ]
}
```

По структуре все ок, все хорошо, но вот если, скажем, комментов больше 1000 в каждом посте. Это будет нормой? Или все же лучше отделить комменты от постов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию максимальный размер одного MongoDB документа — 16 MB. Поэтому вопрос сводится к тому, уместятся ли у вас все комментарии в эти 16MB. Если уместятся, то так делать нормально и удобно, если нет, то нужно обеспечить вынос комментариев в отдельные документы и коллекции.